# Can't install confluent-control center

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

I am new to Kafka and trying to install my ubuntu machine Confluent control center.
Here is the document i have followed : https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html 
I've succesfully built kafka with 3 brokers and zookeeper but there is soem problem in Confluent Control Center.

When i start conf-cont-center

```
sudo systemctl start confluent-control-center
```

The log under the **/var/log/confluent/control-center.log** says that:

```
The state store, commander, may have migrated to another instance.
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappingStoreProvider.stores(WrappingStoreProvider.java:65)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CompositeReadOnlyKeyValueStore.all(CompositeReadOnlyKeyValueStore.java:97)
        at io.confluent.controlcenter.command.CommandMigrator.getActiveControllerCountTriggers(CommandMigrator.java:132)
        at io.confluent.controlcenter.command.CommandMigrator.disableActionsForActiveControllerCountTrigger(CommandMigrator.java:97)
        at io.confluent.controlcenter.command.CommandMigrator.migrate(CommandMigrator.java:57)
        at io.confluent.controlcenter.ControlCenter.main(ControlCenter.java:139)
```

Comment: Is that the entire stacktrace? I don't think this error alone prevents it from starting

Answer (score -1):

Check the version of your Kafka and make sure it’s supported by confluent control center

Comment: OP seems to have used the Debian packages of Confluent, which all work together